# Why can’t I make hellstone?

Tags: terraria

I have obsidian and hellstone ore, but I can’t craft it. I have also tried using a hellforge but it didn’t work either. I think I need molten armor to beat the wall of flesh and I need the Phoenix blaster.

Answer (score 2):

All you need 3 hellstone ore, obsidian and a hellforge.

You can use the hellforges down in the underworld, or take one from there to place in your home base. Crafting will work in either location however.

[wiki link](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hellstone)